# Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, compilation, frameworks

I am using VS 2008 and .Net Framework 3.5 when i compile project i m getting error

Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.

I have checked that csc.exe is also exist in the .net frame work folder.

When i change compiler version 3.5 to 2.0 it starts working but My 3.5 Features are not available there like LINQ.

I have try everything, Update .Net Framework, Install latest service Pack.

Please help me out this Problem.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall visual studio? It might be looking for a different c# compiler then the one you have.

Comment: Very strange. I'd suggest doing a repair of your VS.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the path to csc. Is csc.exe in your v3.5 folder?